# Spyder 3.1.4 - Cannot configure Spyder after OS upgrade

Tags: spyder

I cannot use Spyder 3.1.4 after upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 because I cannot do basic configuration of Spyder itself.

I cannot configure (i.e. Menu `Run | Configure` or Ctrl-F6) I get the following error on the Internal Console

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/editor.py", line 2300, in edit_run_configurations
    dialog.setup(fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/runconfig.py", line 426, in setup
    widget.set(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/runconfig.py", line 260, in set
    self.wd_cb.setChecked(self.runconf.wdir_enabled)
TypeError: setChecked(self, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

I have Spyder 3.1.4 running with Python 2.7.14 64bits, Qt 5.91, PyAt5 5.7 on Linux.

I suppose I can start uninstalling and reinstalling with pip, but I am hoping someone knows what the issue is and perhaps there is an easier solution.

Comment: Please run in a terminal `spyder --reset` and try again. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes `spyder --reset` fixed my problem @CarlosCordoba Thank You!  If you care to post a response I would be happy to mark it as the best solution so you get proper credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run in a system terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe` or `xterm`) `spyder --reset` and try again. That should fix your problem.